# How to run scripts depend on difference stop time

Tags: linux, bash, date, ubuntu, time

Hi I have written a `bash` script which automatically runs my `python` program every 24 hours with updated parameters. After 5-th day it will run with last seated parameters.

I would like to add option such that if the system has been shutoff for more than 6 hours, the script will start from day one option. If not, it will continue from last state.

Currently I am only writing start-time into a file. However I am not sure how can I read time string from this file and use to calculate time difference between start and stop.

I just tried to write date into a file. However I'm not quite sure how to read and use this value in exception.

```
echo "$(date) $(ls -1 | wc -l)" >> starttime.txt
python3 startmeVtest.py 5 2 10
timeout 86400 ./start.sh
sleep 4
python3 startmeVtest.py 10 4 20
timeout 86400 ./start.sh
sleep 4
python3 startmeVtest.py 20 4 40
timeout 86400 ./start.sh
sleep 4
python3 startmeVtest.py 30 8 50
timeout 86400 ./start.sh
sleep 4
python3 startmeVtest.py 50 9 70
./start.sh
```

IF system has been stop less then 6 hours only last script should be executed

```
sleep 4
python3 startmeVtest.py 50 9 70
./start.sh
```

Comment: What do you mean by `After 5-th day it will run with last "seated" parameters`? and `However I'm not quite sure how to read and use this value in exception` ?

Comment: Sorry probably my English not very clear. Seated -> set parameters. And I would like to use time and date value in If operand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a different (or an additional) format in your date command that you dump to starttime.txt.

Instead of:

```
echo "$(date) $(ls -1 | wc -l)" >> starttime.txt
```

Consider:

```
echo "$(date +%s) $(ls -1 | wc -l)" >> starttime.txt
```

The above edit will output the timestamp in epoch time.  Epoch time is the number of seconds since the epoch (typically Jan 1 1970 GMT).  The integer value will make it easier for you to compare the 6 hour time difference:

Here's a little code to see if the last entry in starttime.txt is six hours old:

```
lastrun=$(tail -1 starttime.txt | awk '{print $1}')
currenttime=$(date +%s)
if [ $currenttime -gt $(( lastrun + 6 * 60 * 60 )) ] ; then
  # execute the system has STOP more than 6 hours logic
  :
else
  # execute the system has STOP less than 6 hours log
  :
fi
```

However, you can also make this easier by just looking at the timestamp on starttime.txt and comparing it to another file that is 6 hours old.  Here's another approach using the -ot test. -ot is the older than test. Here's how to apply it to your use case:

```
touch -d "6 hours ago" 6hoursago
if [ starttime.txt -ot 6hoursago ] ; then
  # execute the "system has STOP more than 6 hours logic
  :
else
  # execute the "system has STOP less than six hours
  :
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the last line of the file `starttime.txt` always contains the start time, first you can read that and converted into the number of seconds (since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, see `man date`) as follows.

```
d1="$(date -d "$(cat starttime.txt | sed -nE '$ s/(.*) [0-9]+$/\1/p')" +%s)"
```

Now you can calculate the time difference between `now` and `d1` in seconds.

```
diff="$(( $(date +%s) - d1 ))"
```

You can make the decision with this value.

```
if [[ $diff -gt 21600 ]]; then
    # action if diff is more than 6 hours
else
    # action if diff is less than 6 hours
fi
```

---

Maybe you can simplify your script by moving repeated commands into a function. So the final script will look something like the following.

```
run_script()    # reusable functionality
{
    python3 startmeVtest.py $@
    timeout 86400 ./start.sh
    sleep 4
}

# read the last timestamp first
d1="$(date -d "$(cat starttime.txt | sed -nE '$ s/(.*) [0-9]+$/\1/p')" +%s)"
# then save the current timestamp
echo "$(date) $(ls -1 | wc -l)" >> starttime.txt

# check difference with current time
if [[ "$(( $(date +%s) - d1 ))" -gt 21600 ]]; then
    # action if diff is more than 6 hours
    run_script 50 9 70
else
    # action if diff is less than 6 hours
    run_script 5 2 10
    run_script 10 4 20
    run_script 20 4 40
    run_script 30 8 50
fi

# run following always, irrespective of the time diff
./start.sh
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for Answer!! I have tried next: (for test purpose I used 10 sec)
 d1="$(date -d "$(cat starttime.txt | sed -nE '$ s/(.*) [0-9]+$/\1/p')" +%s)"
echo "$(date) $(ls -1 | wc -l)" >> starttime.txt
if [[ "$(( $(date +%s) - d1 ))" -gt 10 ]]; then
  echo "less then 10 sec"
  #echo $d1
    # action if diff is more than 6 hours
else
    echo "more then 10 sec!!!"
    #echo $d1
fi
And always getting result:
date: invalid date ‘Sun 21 Apr 23:50:32 AEST 2019’
less then 10 sec
and also for some reason in the starttime.txt have number 12 on the end
Sun 21 Apr 23:50:42 AEST 2019 12